# coherence-cache-config.xml is not getting loaded from the specified location

Tags: java, caching, weblogic-10.x, oracle-coherence

I am trying to implement Caching through Oracle coherence. My requirement is to place coherence-cache-config.xml in a path and make this override the same file present in jar.

I have mentioned the path in which I have placed customised coherence-cache-config.xml(which I have named as MyConfig.xml) in Arguements under Environment->CoherenceServers->ServerStart. In the same path where I kept MyConfig.xml, I have also kept tangosol-coherence-override.xml. With this tangosol-coherence-override.xml I have created a cluster in weblogic and have associated to the coherence server I am using.

I have successfully started my coherence server through Admin console of weblogic, even then when hit the coherence server for Cache I get "No scheme for cache:"MyCache"". Please suggest me how can I solve this. Same thing if I open the jar and override the coherence-cache-config.xml then it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Coherence Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15723/gs_config.htm#CEGDFJHH), there are two ways you can specify a custom path for a cache configuration file:

1. Setting up `configurable-cache-factory-config` in `tangosol-coherence-override.xml` file. See example below:

   ```
   <coherence>
       <configurable-cache-factory-config>
           <init-params>
               <init-param>
                   <param-type>java.lang.String</param-type>
                   <param-value system-property="tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig">MyConfig.xml</param-value>
               </init-param>
           </init-params>
       </configurable-cache-factory-config>
   </coherence>
   ```
2. Using `tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig` as a JVM parameter. E.g. `java -Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=MyConfig.xml ...`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a default cache configuration deployment descriptor loaded.

I would recommend to have it overridden with the `tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig` system property specified in your server's start-up script. E.g.:

> java -Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=/your_local_path/MyConfig.xml

To identify what cache configuration deployment descriptor was loaded, please check your coherence's logs - it should contain the following output:

> Loaded cache configuration from resource
>   "file:/your_local_path/MyConfig.xml"